# 1 View per IP or Set Cookie

Tags: php, mysql, html, cookies

Okay I want to allow one user 1 view per each page and then send them a cookie that stops them from viewing that page again, but I am no good with cookies, I'd do it with IP but I'd rather do it via cookies. Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: but when cookie is cleared he will be able to view that page ..

Comment: Can any user view the page, or users are registered with your site??

Comment: Any user, guests and registered, I'd do it via IP's aswell, but I don't want everyone in their household to not be able to view it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest answer:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['myCookie'])){
    die('Not allowed! Only one view per user!');
}
else{
    setcookie('myCookie', true);
}
//content here
```

Doing it with sessions:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['mySession'])){
    die('Not allowed! Only one view per user!');
}
else{
    $_SESSION['mySession'] = true;
}
//content here
```

Redirecting instead of showing an ugly error:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['myCookie'])){
    header('Location: error.php');
    exit;
}
else{
    setcookie('myCookie', true);
}
//content here
```

Comment: Unfortunately, sessions are also based on cookies or preserving Ids in links - so deleting cookie cache will foil both. The same applies to my "answer". Fundamentally, this just isn't the right approach

Comment: I know, but doing it with IP's is easily by passable too. In the longer run I may do with other things, but there's nothing valuable on the other page, so even if they delete their cookies it's no biggie.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['blocked'])) {die('Access denied');}
    setcookie("blocked", true);
?>
```

of course, it's trivial to bypass (Delete cookies).

The real problem you've got is an issue of trust. Cookies are sent to you by the client and you should *never* trust the client.

Fundamentally, if you want to limit access, you either need to keep records server-side of something that can't be changed (eg forcing user to log in, associating with user) or accept that really, you're putting up a very insecure defence.

Note that IP address is no good either since lots of users in a company will likely appear to have the same IP address - so blocking one would block all. Also, some users at home can get a new IP address just by disconnecting/reconnecting their modems/routers

Comment: You're right, but I only want to disallow 1 view per person (computer)

Comment: How important is it? If it's not important, a cookie like this is fine - but anyone with even power-user level knowledge could bypass it. You either need to unqiely identify each user, keep a record of who's seen the page and block server-side or trust the client to tell you the truth and hope it hasn't been modified in any way. Fundamentally, there are no other options. The strength of your solution will depend on a) how unqieuly you're able to identify your visitor or b) how hard it is for the client to fudge the detail(s) you're checking. Fudging cookies is trivial

Comment: Not extremely important. It's nothing that they can edit if they bypass it (it's not an admin panel etc.) Just a piece of text that another use wants them to view only once.

Comment: Then I'd lean towards the cookie solution as a quick 'n dirty fix that isn't very secure but will stop most users who don't actively try to bypass it. Think of it as the "hiding the key under a rock" solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !isset($_COOKIE['visited'][$page_id]) )
{
    // leave him view the page
    $_COOKIE['visited'][$page_id] = true;
}
else
{
    // get him out of there
}
```

This needs to be written at the begginning of the index/page.

But, I do NOT recommend this because the cookies are easily editable by the client. SESSION is the safe way.

Comment: What happens if the user deletes the session cookie?

Comment: @Terry Seidler : God you are so wrong. Basic : the session is destroied.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using:

A) Cookies to limit access (Can be edited by the client)

B) IP Address' (Can be easily changed.)

As @Basic said, Maybe make them log in and only let that user view whatever it is once.

Comment: They'd be able to make another account tho :(

Comment: @NateCorky Which is why most sites force an email address which can be checked as unique. Of course, nowadays everyone has multiple addresses so that's no good either. You're at one end of a very long, ongoing game. It's all about finding a compromise between effort and security. At the most extreme, a user could reformat their system (or less drastically, swap browsers). Now there's absolutely no way you can know it's the same person. Short of meeting everyone face-to-face and giving them an account, it's not possible to guarantee each user is unique

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate :( But I want to let guests view it, only register if the owner of the text file wants to define 1 view per person, which will be nye-impossible. :( I'll just use cookies for the time being until I build a system that's secure(ish)

Comment: May I ask why you are doing this? Is it critical that they can only view something once?